# Android device appearing in adb but not Eclipse

Tags: android, adb

Android debug bridge (adb) recognises a connected phone in usb debugging mode

```
$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 
SH11KPL04620    device
```

But Eclipse doesn't see the same device:

- Run as -> Android application

  - ***Android Device Chooser***
  - Choose a running Android device
  - (none listed)

Comment: Did you try to just restart `Eclipse`?

Comment: enable `USB debugging` in your Phone

Comment: DDMS can see the device (can even take screenshots of the phone) yet still the "Android Device Chooser" is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make Sure Ur use debuging is On
2. Make Sure ur code built version is compatible with device android version
3. ur can try adb reset as shown below:
   [image]

Comment: @OJW whats ur device version?

Comment: That seems to be it - phone was too old to meet the "minimum android version" of the project, so must have been filtered-out in that list.  Reducing android:minSdkVersion makes it work.